# create multiple textures with rotation of original texture and save them in a list

Tags: libgdx, texture2d

Not sure if I am on the right way.

I have a smal texture which I draw multiple times (1000). But I like to have them with different rotations (around 10) for that texture. So I thought to rotate the textures and save the in a list (10) for the reuse (performance).

When my approach is good, how can I rotate an original texture and store it to a new texture (in memory during start) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sprite class that wraps a Texture and provides many useful methods to work with it. For example: scaling, rotating.

So you will have one Texture instance and 10 sprites.

```
Texture texture = new Texture("path.png");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(texture);
    sprite.setSize(..);
    sprite.setRotation(..);
    someList.add(sprite);
}
```

And then you can just select which sprite you want set it's position and draw it:

```
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. But I like to draw that testure multiple times, like a stamp. And I guess a sprite can only be draw once isn't it. I am also not sure if textures are more performant then sprites ?

Comment: @mcflysoft 1. You can change sprite position and draw it another time in one render call 2. This way is much more efficient for memory